# What does domain reduction mean

Tags: calculus

Can any one tell me what does domain reduction mean? can you show me an example for that to make it clear to me?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Can you clarify the context? What does this have to do with calculus? A search on domain reduction turns up "finite group of symmetries of a system of linear equations" ...

Comment: I believe what you are thinking of, is to restrict the domain of a function, in order to have a well-defined inverse function.

Comment: Indeed this is surely the idea of restricting a function to a smaller domain. Do note that occasionally mathematicians (or people in any technical area, really) will intertwine subject-specific jargon with more ubiquitous terms understood by their colloquial meaning, or otherwise rearrange technical terms as if they were just any old words. In particular, "reduction" here is understood in the everyday sense of "something goes from bigger to smaller, more to less"; the phrase "domain reduction" is not itself standard in how it is being used here.

Comment: It means you boil the domain until you get the desired consistency.

Answer (score 1):

You are reducing the range or limit in which the function can act. $F(x)\rightarrow$$G$ where $G$ is an implicit function or an irreducible constant will be non reducible as $R(n)\rightarrow$$F(x)$ for all $N$$\in$$\mathbb{R}$